# Using Hyperledger Fabric Gateway on NodeJS Docker Container

Tags: node.js, docker, express, grpc, hyperledger-fabric

I've configured a Hyperledger Fabric network that's composed of three organizations: One is hosting three orderers nodes and the other two contains two peers each.

In order to interact with the network I'm building a NodeJS + Express Server that will use `hyperledger/fabric-gateway` module for establish the communication. For testing purpose I've installed on the channel "ch1" the java version of [asset-transfer-basic](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/main/asset-transfer-basic) package given by fabric-samples repository.

In my expressJs server I've configured an endpoint that will try to call the "GetAllAssets" function of the network.

```
function envOrDefault(key: string, defaultValue: string): string {
    return process.env[key] || defaultValue;
}

const channelName = envOrDefault('CHANNEL_NAME', 'ch1');
const chaincodeName = envOrDefault('CHAINCODE_NAME', 'basic');

// Path to crypto materials.
const cryptoPath = envOrDefault('CRYPTO_PATH', path.resolve('path', 'to', 'org1'));

// Path to admin private key directory.
const keyDirectoryPath = envOrDefault('KEY_DIRECTORY_PATH', path.resolve(cryptoPath, 'path', 'to', 'keystore'));

// Path to admin certificate.
const certPath = envOrDefault('CERT_PATH', path.resolve(cryptoPath, 'path', 'to', 'signcerts', 'cert.pem'));

// Path to peer tls certificate.
const tlsCertPath = envOrDefault('TLS_CERT_PATH', path.resolve(cryptoPath, 'peer1', 'tls-msp', 'tlscacerts', 'tlsca.pem'));

// Gateway peer endpoint.
const peerEndpoint = envOrDefault('PEER_ENDPOINT', 'localhost:7051');

// Gateway peer SSL host name override.
const peerHostAlias = envOrDefault('PEER_HOST_ALIAS', 'peer1-org1');

// MSP of the organization
const mspId = envOrDefault('MSP_ID', 'org1MSP');


// The configuration object
const configurations: Config = new Config(
    keyDirectoryPath, 
    certPath, 
    tlsCertPath, 
    peerEndpoint, 
    peerHostAlias, 
    mspId
);

const utf8Decoder = new TextDecoder();

app.get("/gateway", async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => { 
    const client: grpc.Client = await configurations.createGrpcClient();
    const identity: Identity = await configurations.createIdentity();
    const signer: Signer = await configurations.createSigner();
    
    const gateway: Gateway = connect({
        client,
        identity,
        signer,
        // Default timeouts for different gRPC calls
        evaluateOptions: () => {
            return { deadline: Date.now() + 5000 }; // 5 seconds
        },
        endorseOptions: () => {
            return { deadline: Date.now() + 15000 }; // 15 seconds
        },
        submitOptions: () => {
            return { deadline: Date.now() + 5000 }; // 5 seconds
        },
        commitStatusOptions: () => {
            return { deadline: Date.now() + 60000 }; // 1 minute
        },
    });

    try{
        let network: Network = gateway.getNetwork(channelName);
        let contract: Contract = network.getContract(chaincodeName);

        await getAllAssets(contract);
        
    } finally {
        gateway.close();
        client.close();
    }
})
```

`configurations.createGrpcClient()`, `configurations.createIdentity()` and `configurations.createSigner()` are defined as follows:

```
async createGrpcClient(): Promise<grpc.Client> {
        const tlsRootCert = await fs.readFile(this._peerTlsPath);
        console.log("TLS Root Cert ----->");
        console.log(tlsRootCert);
        const tlsCredentials = grpc.credentials.createSsl(tlsRootCert);
        return new grpc.Client(this._peerEndpoint, tlsCredentials, {
            'grpc.ssl_target_name_override': this._hostAlias,
        });
}

async createGrpcClient(): Promise<grpc.Client> {
        const tlsRootCert = await fs.readFile(this._peerTlsPath);
        console.log("TLS Root Cert ----->");
        console.log(tlsRootCert);
        const tlsCredentials = grpc.credentials.createSsl(tlsRootCert);
        return new grpc.Client(this._peerEndpoint, tlsCredentials, {
            'grpc.ssl_target_name_override': this._hostAlias,
        });
}

async createIdentity(): Promise<Identity> {
        const credentials: Buffer = await fs.readFile(this._certPath);
        console.log("Credentials Cert ----->");
        console.log(credentials);
        const mspId: string = this._mspId;
        return { mspId, credentials };
    }
```

If I execute the web server directly on my computer this will work, in fact, if I try to start the server and navigate to `/gateway` this will return the assets stored in the blockchain:

```
--> Evaluate Transaction: GetAllAssets, function returns all the current assets on the ledger
*** Result: [
  {
    appraisedValue: 300,
    assetID: 'asset1',
    color: 'blue',
    owner: 'Tomoko',
    size: 5
  },
  {
    appraisedValue: 400,
    assetID: 'asset2',
    color: 'red',
    owner: 'Brad',
    size: 5
  },
  {
    appraisedValue: 500,
    assetID: 'asset3',
    color: 'green',
    owner: 'Jin Soo',
    size: 10
  },
  {
    appraisedValue: 600,
    assetID: 'asset4',
    color: 'yellow',
    owner: 'Max',
    size: 10
  },
  {
    appraisedValue: 700,
    assetID: 'asset5',
    color: 'black',
    owner: 'Adrian',
    size: 15
  },
  {
    appraisedValue: 700,
    assetID: 'asset6',
    color: 'white',
    owner: 'Michel',
    size: 15
  }
]
```

Unfortunately I can't reproduce this behavior using a docker container: I've configured  the following Dockerfile:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:20-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .

RUN npm install
RUN npm run prepare

ENV GRPC_TRACE=all
ENV GRPC_VERBOSITY=DEBUG

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Then builded the image with `docker build . -t test`, launched with `docker run -p:8080:8080 -v /tmp/hyperledger:/tmp/hyperledger --name test test` and, finally, connect to the fabric network (that is built whit docker-compose) using `docker network connect blockchain_fabric-ca test`.

I'm sure that the container is added to the network because If I inspect the network with `docker network inspect blockchain_fabric-ca` "test" is in the list of active containers.

If I navigate on the same endpoint as before I get the following connection error :

```
--> Evaluate Transaction: GetAllAssets, function returns all the current assets on the ledger
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.623Z | channel | (1) dns:localhost:7051 createResolvingCall [0] method="/gateway.Gateway/Evaluate", deadline=2023-08-10T20:03:45.622Z
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.624Z | resolving_call | [0] Created
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.624Z | resolving_call | [0] Deadline: 2023-08-10T20:03:45.622Z
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.625Z | resolving_call | [0] Deadline will be reached in 4997ms
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.626Z | resolving_call | [0] start called
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.627Z | dns_resolver | Looking up DNS hostname localhost
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.628Z | resolving_load_balancer | dns:localhost:7051 IDLE -> CONNECTING
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.628Z | connectivity_state | (1) dns:localhost:7051 IDLE -> CONNECTING
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.628Z | channel | (1) dns:localhost:7051 callRefTimer.ref | configSelectionQueue.length=1 pickQueue.length=0
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.628Z | resolving_call | [0] startRead called
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.629Z | resolving_call | [0] write() called with message of length 1285
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.629Z | resolving_call | [0] halfClose called
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.630Z | dns_resolver | Resolved addresses for target dns:localhost:7051: [::1:7051,127.0.0.1:7051]
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.631Z | subchannel | (2) ::1:7051 Subchannel constructed with options {
  "grpc.ssl_target_name_override": "peer1-org1"
}
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.631Z | subchannel_refcount | (2) ::1:7051 refcount 0 -> 1
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.631Z | subchannel | (3) 127.0.0.1:7051 Subchannel constructed with options {
  "grpc.ssl_target_name_override": "peer1-org1"
}
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.631Z | subchannel_refcount | (3) 127.0.0.1:7051 refcount 0 -> 1
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.631Z | subchannel_refcount | (2) ::1:7051 refcount 1 -> 2
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.632Z | subchannel_refcount | (3) 127.0.0.1:7051 refcount 1 -> 2
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.632Z | pick_first | Start connecting to subchannel with address ::1:7051
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.632Z | pick_first | IDLE -> CONNECTING
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.632Z | resolving_load_balancer | dns:localhost:7051 CONNECTING -> CONNECTING
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.632Z | channel | (1) dns:localhost:7051 callRefTimer.unref | configSelectionQueue.length=1 pickQueue.length=0
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.632Z | connectivity_state | (1) dns:localhost:7051 CONNECTING -> CONNECTING
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.633Z | subchannel | (2) ::1:7051 IDLE -> CONNECTING
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.634Z | transport | dns:localhost:7051 creating HTTP/2 session to ::1:7051
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.637Z | channel | (1) dns:localhost:7051 createRetryingCall [1] method="/gateway.Gateway/Evaluate"
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.637Z | resolving_call | [0] Created child [1]
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.637Z | retrying_call | [1] start called
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.637Z | channel | (1) dns:localhost:7051 createLoadBalancingCall [2] method="/gateway.Gateway/Evaluate"
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.637Z | retrying_call | [1] Created child call [2] for attempt 1
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.638Z | load_balancing_call | [2] start called
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.638Z | load_balancing_call | [2] Pick called
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.638Z | load_balancing_call | [2] Pick result: QUEUE subchannel: null status: undefined undefined
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.638Z | channel | (1) dns:localhost:7051 callRefTimer.ref | configSelectionQueue.length=0 pickQueue.length=1
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.638Z | retrying_call | [1] startRead called
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.638Z | load_balancing_call | [2] startRead called
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.639Z | retrying_call | [1] write() called with message of length 1290
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.639Z | load_balancing_call | [2] write() called with message of length 1290
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.639Z | retrying_call | [1] halfClose called
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.641Z | transport | dns:localhost:7051 connection failed with error connect EADDRNOTAVAIL ::1:7051 - Local (:::0)
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.641Z | subchannel | (2) ::1:7051 CONNECTING -> TRANSIENT_FAILURE
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.641Z | pick_first | Start connecting to subchannel with address 127.0.0.1:7051
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.641Z | subchannel | (3) 127.0.0.1:7051 IDLE -> CONNECTING
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.641Z | transport | dns:localhost:7051 creating HTTP/2 session to 127.0.0.1:7051
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.644Z | transport | dns:localhost:7051 connection failed with error connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:7051
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.644Z | subchannel | (3) 127.0.0.1:7051 CONNECTING -> TRANSIENT_FAILURE
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.644Z | pick_first | CONNECTING -> TRANSIENT_FAILURE
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.644Z | resolving_load_balancer | dns:localhost:7051 CONNECTING -> TRANSIENT_FAILURE
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.644Z | channel | (1) dns:localhost:7051 callRefTimer.unref | configSelectionQueue.length=0 pickQueue.length=0
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.644Z | load_balancing_call | [2] Pick called
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.644Z | load_balancing_call | [2] Pick result: TRANSIENT_FAILURE subchannel: null status: 14 No connection established
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.644Z | connectivity_state | (1) dns:localhost:7051 CONNECTING -> TRANSIENT_FAILURE
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.645Z | load_balancing_call | [2] ended with status: code=14 details="No connection established"
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.645Z | retrying_call | [1] Received status from child [2]
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.645Z | retrying_call | [1] state=TRANSPARENT_ONLY handling status with progress PROCESSED from child [2] in state ACTIVE
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.645Z | retrying_call | [1] ended with status: code=14 details="No connection established"
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.645Z | resolving_call | [0] Received status
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.646Z | resolving_call | [0] ended with status: code=14 details="No connection established"
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.647Z | subchannel_refcount | (2) ::1:7051 refcount 2 -> 1
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.647Z | subchannel_refcount | (3) 127.0.0.1:7051 refcount 2 -> 1
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.647Z | connectivity_state | (1) dns:localhost:7051 TRANSIENT_FAILURE -> SHUTDOWN
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.647Z | subchannel_refcount | (2) ::1:7051 refcount 1 -> 0
D 2023-08-10T20:03:40.647Z | subchannel_refcount | (3) 127.0.0.1:7051 refcount 1 -> 0
/usr/src/app/node_modules/@hyperledger/fabric-gateway/dist/gatewayerror.js:39
    return new GatewayError({
           ^

GatewayError: 14 UNAVAILABLE: No connection established
    at newGatewayError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@hyperledger/fabric-gateway/dist/gatewayerror.js:39:12)
    at Object.callback (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@hyperledger/fabric-gateway/dist/client.js:101:67)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:192:36)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:360:141)
    ... 2 lines matching cause stack trace ...
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11) {
  code: 14,
  details: [],
  cause: Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: No connection established
      at callErrorFromStatus (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:19)
      at Object.onReceiveStatus (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:192:76)
      at Object.onReceiveStatus (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:360:141)
      at Object.onReceiveStatus (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:323:181)
      at /usr/src/app/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/resolving-call.js:99:78
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)
  for call at
      at Client.makeUnaryRequest (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:160:32)
      at /usr/src/app/node_modules/@hyperledger/fabric-gateway/dist/client.js:44:110
      at new Promise (<anonymous>)
      at GatewayClientImpl.evaluate (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@hyperledger/fabric-gateway/dist/client.js:44:16)
      at ProposalImpl.evaluate (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@hyperledger/fabric-gateway/dist/proposal.js:50:96)
      at async getAllAssets (/usr/src/app/dist/app.js:86:25)
      at async /usr/src/app/dist/app.js:77:9 {
    code: 14,
    details: 'No connection established',
    metadata: Metadata { internalRepr: Map(0) {}, options: {} }
  }
}
```

Have someone faced a similar issue? What I want to achieve is to create a separated docker-compose file for my node server (that will integrate other services like MongoDB) that is able to communicate with my fabric network.
I'll thank you in advance for your precious help.

Comment: Your Dockerfile and `docker run` command indicate that your docker container should be serving on port 8080, but the error log indicates that the client is trying to connect to port 7051.

Comment: @murgatroid99, Thanks for your response. The docker container is serving on port 8080 and that's ok because there will be served the rest api service. The connection to 7051 is directed to one peer of my HF organization and it's established by the grpc client, as reported in my code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see `const peerEndpoint = envOrDefault('PEER_ENDPOINT', 'localhost:7051');`.
But  the keyword `localhost` within a container refers to the container itself, not the host machine or any other containers, including those that might be linked or connected.

Given your current setup, you have both the [Fabric](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gateway.html) network and the Node.js application running in separate containers. Hence, the error`No connection established` because the Node.js application is trying to connect to `localhost`, which in this context refers to the Node.js application container itself, not the Fabric peer container.

When you add your Node.js container to the Fabric network, make sure they are on the same network. You can then communicate with another container using its container name. For instance, if your peer's container name is `peer0.org1.example.com`, you would use that as the hostname instead of `localhost`.

If you are going to be moving between running your app natively and in a container, consider parameterizing the peer endpoint (and potentially other configuration items) using environment variables or a configuration file. That will allow you to easily change the settings based on where the app is running.

A possible docker compose could be:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    image: test
    container_name: test
    environment:
      - PEER_ENDPOINT=peer1-org1:7051
      # any other environment variables you need 
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - /tmp/hyperledger:/tmp/hyperledger
    networks:
      - fabric_net

  peer1-org1:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest
    # your peer's configuration, environment, volumes, etc. 
    networks:
      - fabric_net
  
  # other services (orderers, other peers, CAs, etc.) 

networks:
  fabric_net:
```

Comment: Yhea that was the problem!